# Best way to create tiles

Tags: geoserver, tiles

Within a GeoServer framework, does anybody know how I might best create/cache tiles based on layers stored in PostGIS?  I am aware of Mapnik and have created a simple TMS using python (+ Django) but this seems 'clunky' and I'd like to know if there are any better ways to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check http://tilecache.org/ 
TileCache provides a Python-based WMS-C/TMS server, with pluggable caching mechanisms and rendering backends. I

And

http://geowebcache.org/
GeoWebCache is a Java web application used to cache map tiles coming from a variety of sources such as OGC Web Map Service (WMS). It implements various service interfaces (such as WMS-C, WMTS, TMS, Google Maps KML, Virtual Earth) in order to accelerate and optimize map image delivery. It can also recombine tiles to work with regular WMS clients.
As user1702401 commented it can be integrated in geoserver: http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/introduction/whichgwc.html

Comment: Since you are using GeoServer, GeoWebCache would be obvious choice.

Comment: TileCache seems stuck on version 2.11. Sometimes I wonder if it is alive, because this release has already some years. Anyway, TileCache is a great software although the seeder application has the annoyance of aborting when the cached WMS service cannot, for whatever reason, generate a requested tile; an additional problem is that you cannot tell seeder application to resume from the tile that caused it to stop.